# replace string in json file run time using python

Tags: python, json

In my code have block where data to be written in json file, I am able to dump data but it is not dumping in the way which I want.
sample json:

```
{val2: data2}
{val3: data3}
```

where I want the data to be stored like below:

```
{ val1: data1, val2: data2, val3: data3}
```

logic in my code:

```
with open("cache_metadata.json", "a+") as f:
   json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

here it is opening file when there is data to be updated, so is there a way that i can put some login under this block to replace {} with ,?
Also have tried that from google but somehow in last extra } still there.

Comment: To do that, you `json.load` the whole file into a single dict, then update the dict, then `json.dump` the whole dict out to the file.  Very common with JSON.

Comment: Both your input and your output are not valid JSON.

Comment: @KlausD. sorry? not getting your point

Comment: you can check the validity of your json data online (http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: Hello, can you join the chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250263/python-question-room